# How do I change my localhost to domain server

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am learning how to build a website, so I did one and now I uploaded it to a domain server. I want to change my database connection from

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","student");
```

To a domain sever.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not domain server. It might be hosting server. You need to set up new database in there from cPanel or somethings control platform and import your local database. If you use share hosting, you will not get root access. You will need to change yr connection string with server IP or somethings like localhost, db username, and password in PHP script.

Comment: I've created the database already in the cpanel and I've change the username from root to the given username and also I change the host name to the given host name and as well the database name, but still it didn't work

Comment: What I need to understand is how to link my database from my cpanel to my website

Comment: it use 'localhost' mostly to link with database. username might be use with yr database user name  which u created. Database name is also need to fill to know from yr php script